# how can i optimize my network/server's performance in order for axios interceptor to work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, performance, server, axios

Right now, it takes forever for my axios interceptor to run before requests,
What happens is that the loading stops, I get a message of text on my screen that says "paused in debugger",
the developer tools open and in utils.js and const keys is highlighted for me, here is what I find:

```
    // Iterate over object keys
    const keys = allOwnKeys ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) : Object.keys(obj);
    const len = keys.length;
    let key;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      key = keys[i];
      fn.call(null, obj[key], key, obj);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to optimize my intereptor's performance to mitigate this?

Here is my axios instance and interceptor :

```
import axios from 'axios';


const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3005',
  withCredentials: true,
  timeout: 5000, // set a timeout of 5 seconds
});

// Add a request interceptor to check the validity of the access token
instance.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
   
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  try {
    // Send a request to the /api/checkToken endpoint to verify the access token
    await instance.get('/checkToken', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      withCredentials: true
    });
    console.log('req was sent to checkToken!')
  } catch (error) {
    // If the access token is invalid, send a request to the /api/refreshToken endpoint to get a new access token
    const response = await instance.post('/refreshToken', {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      withCredentials: true
    });
    console.log('req was sent to refreshToken!')
    // Set the new access token as the authorization header for all subsequent requests
    const newToken = response.data.newAccessToken;
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.newAccessToken}`;
    console.log(newToken);
  }
  
  return config;
}, (error) => {
  // Handle request errors here
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default instance;
```

Here is the checkToken and refreshToken endpoints used in the axios intereptor`enter code here`, is it possible that they are running in a loop?

```
export const checkToken = (req, res) => {
  // Get the token from the request headers
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

  try {
    // Verify the token and decode its payload
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    // If the token is not expired, send a success response
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Token is valid' });
  } catch (error) {
    // If the token is expired or invalid, send an error response
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid or expired token' });
  }
};
-----------

export const refreshHandle = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {

      const rToke = req.headers.cookie
      if(!rToke) return res.status(401).json({message:'unauthorized'});
      
      const refreshToken = rToke.split('=')[1];

        const decodedRefreshToken = jwt.verify(
          refreshToken,
          process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET
        );
        console.log(decodedRefreshToken, 'refresh token was verified!')
      
      const newAccessToken = jwt.sign(
        { userId: decodedRefreshToken.userId },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: "3m" }
      );

      // res.cookie("refreshToken", newRefreshToken, { httpOnly: true });
          res.json({token : newAccessToken})

        next();
      } catch (err) {
        const error = new HttpError('Authentication failed', 401);
        return next(error);
      }
}
```

Here is a redux action that I use instance on :

```
export const saveProductAction = (productId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { token } = getState().auth;
  console.log(token);
  const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
  };
  const url = `http://localhost:3005/product/${productId}/save`;
  try {
    const response = await instance.put(url, null, config);
    console.log(response.data)
    dispatch(saveProduct(response.data.productId));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    console.error(error?.response?.data ?? error.message);

  }
};
```

What should I do so that axios interceptor runs fasters with better performance?
This problem occurs with every request I use interceptor with.

If anything, could someone give me some tips on if my network is the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to solve with this short lived token? Can it be stored for longer? If not, can this token just be generated right before a request, rather than some amount of time before it (which requires it to be checked/refreshed)?

Comment: @MattCarlotta The reason the token is short lived is in order to test if my interceptor works at getting a newAccessToken before a request if my current accessToken expired, and then resending a new request with the newAccessToken. An accessToken is generated when a user logs in

Comment: I understand the intent of the interceptor, but I'm still a bit confused as to the purpose of the token and why you want to generate it to be short lived after a login event (this puts a 3m time constraint on when the token can be used). For example, if you know a customer is logged in, can you just generate an even shorter lived token (for example, 5s) for that specific request for that specific customer?

Comment: When I worked for an eCommerce company, we would generate a short lived token before some sort of auth event for a 3rd party vendor. Without the token, the request would be denied by the vendor. However, we only generated this short lived token for that specific request. This way, we didn't need to manually check if the token was stale, since it was essentially guaranteed to be fresh per request.

Comment: If you're not working with a 3rd party vendor or a vendor that lives on a different domain, I'd recommend just setting a longer lived token as a cookie. This way, it'll automatically be included on all requests when the `withCredentials` property is set. On your server, there would be middleware for each auth route that checks if this cookie token exists and is valid. If the token isn't valid, then simply deny the request. This simplifies the process of having to generate & check the token without creating a request waterfall.